# Como excluir div pelo nome da classe usando WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, html, navegador-de-internet

Considerando este código:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <p>Informações Adicionais</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">

    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>
        <strong>Data: </strong> 01/01/2016 21:05 à 02/02/2016 23:59
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>Situação:</strong>  <span class="js-bootstrap-tooltip" title=""></span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <strong>Nota: </strong>  <span style="color: #"></span>
      </li>

      <li>
        <strong>Correção: </strong> 01/01/2016 21:05 à 02/02/2016 23:59</div>
      </li>
  </ul>
  <hr />
  <h5>Arquivos</h5>
  <hr />
  <p class="mb-10 alert alert-danger">Mensagem .....</p>

</div>
<footer id="footer" class="page-footer">
  <h6 class="pull-left no-margin">EMPRESA 1.0.0</h6>
  <h6 class="copyright pull-right no-margin">&copy; 2016 TESTE</h6>
  <a href="#acessibilidade" class="screen-reader">Retornar ao topo</a>
</footer>
```

Acima temos o código fonte do site que é executado dentro do `WebBrowser`. Temos duas partes, a segunda parte eu consigo remover com o seguinte código:

```
HTMLDocumentClass htmldoc=web_Pagina.Document.DomDocument as HTMLDocumentClass;
IHTMLDOMNode node=htmldoc.getElementById("footer") as IHTMLDOMNode;
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Mas como posso remover o que existe dentro da div com o classe `panel panel-default`?

Comment: Você conseguiu solucionar o problema?

Answer (score 2):

Você quer obter um elemento pelo atributo class, certo?

Você precisa criar um método que faça isso para você. Basta iterar todos os elementos do documento html verificando seu atributo className e comparar com o que você procura.

```
static IEnumerable<HtmlElement> GetElementByClass(HtmlDocument documento, string classe)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement elemento in documento.All)
        if (elemento.GetAttribute("className") == classe)
            yield return elemento;
}
```

Com o método acima basta usar ele pra encontrar o nó desejado e excluí-lo igual ao nó com id footer:

```
HTMLDocumentClass htmldoc = web_Pagina.Document.DomDocument as HTMLDocumentClass;
IHTMLDOMNode node = GetElementByClass(htmldoc, "panel panel-default")[0] as IHTMLDOMNode;
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Comment: Boa dica, mas o autor da pergunta foi claro que ele quer "excluir" o elemento e não apenas obter, recomendo que edite a resposta

Comment: Bem observado @GuilhermeNascimento, resposta editada.

Answer (score 1):

Para o código acima ficar completo e correto, é necessário converter o primeiro o elemento (htmldoc) que está sendo passado por parâmetro de "`HTML Document Class`" para "`HTML Document`".

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' to 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument'
```